# Controll of urdf on gazebo with ros topics

Tags: ros, gazebo, topic, joint-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've managed to create an urdf file and can simulate it in gazebo. It consists of a 3 finger gripper so the joints are all revolute. Now I want to be able to rotate them on gazebo or rviz, this is, open and close the gripper, with a ROS topic. How am I able to do that? I cant publish the topic but can't make the model move since I can't make it subscribe the message. I think that I have to use the topic "hand_command" and the msg "trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory". Is there any tutorial on this or can anyone give me some help? The gripper is based on the model found on the link of  [shadow hand smart grasping sandbox](https://github.com/shadow-robot/smart_grasping_sandbox).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280449/controll-of-urdf-on-gazebo-with-ros-topics/) by [JuanTelo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32449/juantelo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2018-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's a place you can start: http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20a%20URDF%20in%20Gazebo

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1